# How does vector to vector copy work in c++?

Tags: c++

I have the following vector-to-vector copy.

```
vec_a = vec_b;
```

Here, `vec_a` and `vec_b` holds `vec_structurename` elements.

Structure definition is something like this.

```
typedef struct{
    uint16 name;
    other_strctuname info;
}vec_structurename;
```

My question is when we do vector-to-vector copy here. What's the expectation?. Will it call a single memcpy or will it call `vec_b.size()` number of memcpy implicitly?

Comment: why do you think it would use `memcpy` ? What is `other_strctuname` ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D

Comment: If a vector contains classes it must also copy those classes and make instances of those classes (using memcpy would not result in the copy having objects in a correct/constructed state). The expectation is that you get a valid copy for each and every element in the vector.

Comment: Question back : why is this important to you? Do you have performance issues?

Comment: suppose `a` and `b` are instances of `vec_structurename`, then I suggest you to first understand what `a = b` means in detail. And already for that you included too little details. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: What makes you think `memcpy` is involved at all?

Comment: There are a lot of circumstances in which `memcpy()` cannot be used - for example, if `other_strctuname` is a non-trivial type.  Even if `memcpy()` *can* be used, there is no requirement that it will be - that decision is up to the implementer of the compiler and its associated standard library and amounts to a QOI (quality of implementation) concern.

Comment: Minor point: you don't need to the `typedef struct { ... } name;` dance in C++. `struct name { ... };` works just fine. The typedef thing is from C, where struct names were in their own namespace, and you had to say `struct name *ptr;` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's closer to this.  Or more appropriately, this is how you should think about it:

```
// vec_a = vec_b
//
vec_a.clear();
vec_a.reserve(vec_b.size());  // OR vec_a.reserve(vec_b.capacity()) 
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec_b.size(); i++) {
    vec_b.push_back(vec_b[i]);
}
```

However, the compiler is free to optimize a vector copy with a memory allocation for vec_a followed by a memcpy like copy for plain-old-value types and trivially copyable structs.

Otherwise, when  each push_back call is invoking the copy constructor of each

```
vec_a[i] = vec_structurename(vec_b[i]);
```

Without an explicitly copy constructor, it will be a member by member assignment:

Which in the case of your data structure, is mostly this:

```
vec_a[i].name = vec_b[i].name;
vec_a[i].other_strctuname  = vec_b[i].other_strctuname;
```

Same goes for the assignment of `other_strctuname`. It will either make use of the copy constructor of that class or fallback to member by member assignment.

Again, if everything is trivially copyable, the compiler is free to do a quick allocation and memcpy.

Here's a Godbolt example using your class as an example with different types. For the trivially copyable classes, you can see the new + memcpy getting invoked within the inline assembly.  For the struct that has a string, it has to do something else.

https://www.godbolt.org/z/o973PeGx1

Answer (score -1):

just call a single memcpy,because the source is the elements are stored in a continuous block of memory,just easy copy.

Comment: What if the vectors are of different size?

Comment: in general this is wrong. If `other_strctuname` contains eg a `std::string` or anything else that is not trivially copyable then a memcpy will result in a broken copy

Comment: What do you mean?  `std::memcpy(&vec_a, &vec_b, sizeof vec_a);`?